# Persistance XSS attack during OutputStream.write()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xss

I have been working over the security issue regarding the persistent-XSS attack and i was able to analyze the issue using fortify.

**sends unvalidated data to a web browser , which can result in the browser executing malicious code.**

Code is in Java.

```
void output(OutputStream out){
  out.write(byteData);  //byteData is a data member of the class of type byte[].
}
```

At line (2) in above snippet i am getting the notification of xss attack.
So how can i validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to validate your data before sending it to your `OutputStream`

```
void output(OutputStream out) {
    // Validate byteData code here
    out.write(byteData);
}
```

Validation means checking if the code abides by the rules that you want to set for it. For example, if you want to send only numbers, you can make sure that your byteData contains only numbers before sending it.

Comment: but can byte data be attacked by xss?

Comment: If your data gets attacked before it gets converted into bytes you're still sending malicious data to your server.

Comment: but i am getting a byte array and i don't know whether its from an html or xls or any other.Does converting it to string(i.e. new String(byteData))  and then again stringifying it won't it corrupt the bytes?

Comment: if you get an XSS script from a html page, it gets converted into a byte array, you send the bytes to your server. on your server it reads the bytes and then reads the XSS code and because it's a script, it'll run directly on your server. This goes for any type of data. As for the validation, that completely depends on what you want to allow to go through to your server.

Comment: Do you have any good techniques that i can use for validation? I am working over a legacy code, in which the html file is generated dynamically and there's lot of code how can i verify each tag for the script.It could be anywhere.In header,href,rel...

Comment: Validation is completely dependent on what you want, I can't help you with that. I'm sorry

Comment: JREN, I came accross [OWASP Antisamy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project). Its actually for .html not for .xls or for any other format.

Comment: If I convert the file(lets generalize it..can be anything excel,pdf,doc) into string and again to bytes won't it effect the formatting/corrupt the data?